# Print NULL in c

Tags: c, null, segmentation-fault

I'm re-implementing `printf` in C.
I noticed that when you pass a NULL as a string:

```c
printf("%s", NULL);
```

It returns different output depending on the architecture of the device.
When executed on a Mac, the output is `(null)`, but on Linux the output is `NULL`, I guess.

I know it should be an undefined behavior, but the original `printf` handles that
so I want to do that too.  So my question is, how can I print that `NULL` or `(null)`
without having to hard-code the function to check the architecture and print the output accordingly.

In my code, I check if the passed pointer is `null`.
If so I converted that null to a `string` `(char *)0`

```c
void _ftprintf(const char *fmt, va_list *argp, t_flags f)
    ... somecode for other flags and specifiers ...
    c = *++fmt;
    else if (c == 's')
    {
     ... some other code to deal with precision and width ...
     if (p == NULL)
         p = (char *)0;
     while (*p)
         printchar(*p++);
    }
    ... some other code for other specifiers ...
```

But that failed, I get seg fault probably because I'm trying to access a null pointer which points to an invalid object.

I tried to look at the assembly code but didn't help as I don't understand it. this is what I tried:
https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/dn9f7bEYn

Comment: Shouldn't that be something like `p = "(null)";`? You don't want `p` to be zero because you can't dereference zero.

Comment: You want the function to print different things depending on the architecture, but you don't want "to *hard-code* the function to check the architecture and print the output accordingly." [italics added] What alternative can you possibly have in mind?

Comment: It doesn't vary according to architecture. It varies according to C library implementation. And GNU's glibc, which is the most common libc implementation on Linux, prints `(null)`, just like whatever C library you are using on your Mac. Other C libraries segfault, or do something else. So do whatever you want but don't pretend that you are mimicing something is "standard for your architecture". Because you're not. Because there is no standard for undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Beta I didn't know that it depends on the implementation as @rici said. So I will just make my own implementation. I thought the function is returning some value and depending on how the device work it will print it as `(null)` or `NULL`, but @rici cleared that it depends on the implementation. so I'll just do whatever I want with it. thanks both. anyway, should I delete this post, I think other people can search about printing null in c, it may be usefull for someone. or should I answer my question?

Comment: It's a nuisance that the implementations don't forcibly crash.  Passing NULL to `printf()` for a `%s` format is undefined behaviour according to the C standard.  And a crash would remind people that they should not abuse `printf()` like that.  And the original `printf()` on a PDP-11 probably crashed.